Let $a_{n} > 0$ and $\sum a_{n}$ converges. Prove that $\forall p > \frac{1}{2}$ , $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_{n}}}{n^{p}}$ converges.
Question
Let $a_{n} > 0$ and $\sum a_{n}$ converges. Prove that $\forall p > \frac{1}{2}$,  $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_{n}}}{n^{p}}$ converges.
Attempt.
Since, $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n} = 0$. After certain $n$ all the terms in the sequence $a_{n}$ will be less than 1. Thus I am not able to apply comparison test fruitfully here. Every approach that I am trying is facing the issue that $\sqrt{a_{n}} > a_{n}$. I have the intuition that somehow I have to use $n^{p}$ in the denominator so that comparison test can be applied. But I am not able to do so. Please help.

Do you know the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

If $x, y$ are two vectors in Euclidean space then  $|(x,y)|^{2} \leq (x,x)(y,y)$ where $(x,y)$ denote an inner product. How is that useful here?

Fix $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and apply the inequality with $$x_n=\sqrt{a_n}, 1\leqslant n\leqslant N,$$ and $$y_n=n^{-p}, 1\leqslant n\leqslant N.$$  Then $$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n^p} = (x,y) \leqslant \sqrt{(x,x)(y,y)} =\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n}\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^{2p}}}. $$
The right side stays uniformly bounded as $N\to\infty$ because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges (and the terms are non-negative) and $p>1/2$.
